# Android split function behavior

Tags: android, sqlite, split

There is a txt file that looks like:

[image]

It is being splitted by a delimiter ":" well:

```
            temp = strLine.split(":");

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            initialValues.put(TITLE, temp[0].trim());
            initialValues.put(DESCRIPTION, temp[1].trim());
            initialValues.put(GROUP, temp[2].trim());
            initialValues.put(COL1, temp[3].trim());
            initialValues.put(COL2, temp[4].trim());
            initialValues.put(COL3, temp[5].trim());
            initialValues.put(ADDRESS, temp[6].trim());

            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }
```

As you can see this script fills the database. After that I'm displaying a list of data retrieved from database.

But when the .txt does not contain data for ADDRESS field:

[image]

Then inserting function returns "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and the cursor becomes null.

It's OK for database to have null in ADDRESS column, so how to overcome this issue in  **initialValues.put(ADDRESS, temp[6].trim());**

What can you suggest? Thanks

Comment: have you defined any size for temp array?

Comment: Its obvious it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when address will be null

Comment: superb, so should I use some clauses on each column?

Comment: yes, you need to check null on last clause if your sure you can get only adress as null not other fields also

Comment: no, if other fields are empty it is working, it happens only on a last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try to replace this line
initialValues.put(ADDRESS, temp.length>6 ? temp[6].trim():"");
```

Comment: becz your address field at 7 position if you dont have address then your splited array size must be less then 7 that y i have check if size is grater then 6....

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition for Address

```
    temp = strLine.split(":");

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

    initialValues.put(TITLE, temp[0].trim());
    initialValues.put(DESCRIPTION, temp[1].trim());
    initialValues.put(GROUP, temp[2].trim());
    initialValues.put(COL1, temp[3].trim());
    initialValues.put(COL2, temp[4].trim());
    initialValues.put(COL3, temp[5].trim());


    if(temp.length==7)
    {
        initialValues.put(ADDRESS, temp[6].trim());
    }
    else
    {
        initialValues.put(ADDRESS, "");
    }
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```